# Correct way to set state after redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux

What's the correct way to set the state after a redux action is called? Before I used to do it using the componentWillReceiveProps but now as I read, it's considered legacy and should be avoided. The question is, how should I set the state without this method?

I'll give you an example:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProfile();
  }
```

Let's say I call this getProfile action in componentDidMount() and as a result I get a profile object which among other things, contains a simple string field, let's say `color: "red".`

Based on this color field that I got from calling getProfile(), I want to setState and call another redux action without performing any click action or anything. I want to call `this.props.getFavoriteColor(this.state.color)`
What's the best practice?

Comment: Why not dispatch `getFavoriteColor` inside the `getProfile` action creator?

Comment: Do you really need to set component state if you are using redux and the value is there?

Comment: @Li357 your answer helped me solve the problem and understand how should I approach this. Maybe you can post an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)
```

The new function which main responsibility is ensuring that the state and props are in sync for when it is required. It’s main job is replacing componentWillReceiveProps

checkout the docus: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below:

```
async componentDidMount() {
const {color} = await this.props.getProfile();
this.props.getFavoriteColor(color)
}
```